# Loading appropriate property file based on system property mode(Dev/Prod/UAT)

Tags: java, spring

My rest clients will set system property `service.mode` as prod or uat or dev. Based on this property the corresponding properties of one the files `dev.properties,prod.properties,uat.properties` should be loaded. This property will be used by the different service beans defined spring's applicationContext.xml.

What is the best way to load the appropriate property based on system property `service.mode`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your spring config file. Like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:${service.mode}</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

And then you can access those properties like this in your beans

```
<bean id="initSystemStatus" class="xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.InitSystemStatus">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${application.context.instanceID:0001}" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${application.context.timeout:2000}"/>
</bean>
```

**N.B.**

In `${application.context.instanceID:0001}`, `0001` is the default value if the property `application.context.instanceID` is not provided in the properies file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as follows

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>${service.mode}.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Now when you start the rest client, make sure to pass `service.mode`
from prompt (e.g. `-Dservice.mode=uat`)

**EDIT**:

If the `service.mode` is not provided then use the following configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>${service.mode:prod}.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Note the way in which property is mentioned `${service.mode:prod}`. This means that if `service.mode` could not be resolved any how then the default value i.e. `prod` will be picked up.

**NOTE:** This works only with SPRING 3.X

Comment: Well the configuration of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is same but if you closely example the question of OP, he needs a flag (dev/uat etc) that will let the application choose the property file. User will just pass dev/uat and not dev.properties/uat.properties which you are assuming.

Comment: service.mode is not provided can `PropertyPlaceholderConfigure` be made to pick a default say prod.poroperties file.